# Having trouble with an applet and object tags that move paragraphs around

Tags: java, html, object, applet

I'm in a web development class using HTML and CSS. This week's assignment is about multimedia, and we have to embed 3 object tags in a page. The first object is a Java applet that is supposed to display four buttons for external links. If the user doesn't have Java enabled, it's supposed to display just the external links. We are to use conditional if statements to accommodate for the difference between IE, FF, and Chrome. The problem I'm having is that whenever I load the page in Chrome or IE with Java enabled, I get a white box that is the right size, but instead of the four buttons, it says Error. Click for details. When I click it, it says NullPointerException There was an error while executing the application. Click "Details" for more information. In FF with Java enabled, I just get the four links.

The second and third object tags are sound clips of poetry readings. The poems are to be side by side. The objects are to use the QuickTime plugin, and display only the play button. If the user doesn't have QuickTime, it is to display a download link for the .mp3 file. We are to use conditional if statements to accommodate for the difference between IE, FF, and Chrome. The way I have the HTML now, The poems appear side by side and the play button is displayed correctly, however it also displays the download link above the poems. If I change the HTML to the way our book showed us, one poem is over top of the other. I assume this has something to do with the IE conditional if statements, but I don't know and our professor isn't very available right now because of a hospitalized parent.

If anybody can help me figure this out, it would be greatly appreciated. I don't just want the answer, I want to know why something is wrong. HTML and CSS below.

HTML

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>The Robert Frost Web Page</title>
   <link href="poetry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>
   <div id="pageContent">

   <div id="links">
        <!--[if IE]><!-->
        <object classid="clsd:clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
                codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0./jinstall-6-windows-i586.cab"
                type="application/x-java-applet"
                width="700" height="30">
                <param name="code" value="PopMenu.class" />
                <param name="labelpos" value="right" />
                <param name="src0" value="button0.gif" />     
                <param name="src1" value="button1.gif"/>     
                <param name="src2" value="button2.gif"/>     
                <param name="src3" value="button3.gif"/>     
                <param name="text0" value="Robert Frost on Wikipedia"/>     
                <param name="text1" value="Robert Frost at Poets.org"/>     
                <param name="text2" value="Robert Frost Out Loud"/>     
                <param name="text3" value="Robert Frost: America's Poet"/>     
                <param name="href0" value="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost"/>     
                <param name="href1" value="http://www.poets.org/poet.php/prmPID/192"/>     
                <param name="href2" value="http://robertfrostoutloud.com"/>     
                <param name="href3" value="http://www.ketzle.com/frost"/>     

         <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost">Robert Frost on Wikipedia</a>
         <a href="http://www.poets.org/poet.php/prmPID/192">Robert Frost at Poets.org</a>
         <a href="http://robertfrostoutloud.com">Robert Frost Out Loud</a>
         <a href="http://www.ketzle.com/frost">Robert Frost: America's Poet</a>
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE]><!-->
        <object classid="java:PopMenu.class" type="application/x-java-applet"
                width="700" height="30">   
                <param name="labelpos" value="right" />
                <param name="src0" value="button0.gif" />     
                <param name="src1" value="button1.gif"/>     
                <param name="src2" value="button2.gif"/>     
                <param name="src3" value="button3.gif"/>     
                <param name="text0" value="Robert Frost on Wikipedia"/>     
                <param name="text1" value="Robert Frost at Poets.org"/>     
                <param name="text2" value="Robert Frost Out Loud"/>     
                <param name="text3" value="Robert Frost: America's Poet"/>     
                <param name="href0" value="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost"/>     
                <param name="href1" value="http://www.poets.org/poet.php/prmPID/192"/>     
                <param name="href2" value="http://robertfrostoutloud.com"/>     
                <param name="href3" value="http://www.ketzle.com/frost"/>     

         <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Frost">Robert Frost on Wikipedia</a>
         <a href="http://www.poets.org/poet.php/prmPID/192">Robert Frost at Poets.org</a>
         <a href="http://robertfrostoutloud.com">Robert Frost Out Loud</a>
         <a href="http://www.ketzle.com/frost">Robert Frost: America's Poet</a>
        </object>
        <!--<![endif]-->  
   </div>

   <h1 id="head"><img src="rflogo.gif" alt="The Robert Frost Web Page" /></h1>

   <p class="firstp">Robert Frost was born in San Francisco on March 26, 1874. 
      While still a young boy, Frost's father died and the family moved to  
      Massachusetts. Frost attended Dartmouth College for less than a semester, 
      after which he moved back to Massachusetts to teach and work as a reporter 
      for a local newspaper. Frost returned to college in 1897 to attend Harvard, 
      but he did not graduate. Frost was essentially a self-educated man.</p>

    <p>After Harvard, Frost married and sold the farm he had inherited. With
       the proceeds of the sale, he moved his family to England, where he wrote for
       ten years without success. His first works were published by a
       London publisher in 1913.</p>

   <p>Frost's works, once printed, met immediate acclaim. His collection of
      poems <i>A Further Place</i> won the Pulitzer Prize in 1937. Though he is
      sometimes cast as a pastoral poet, Frost was also a fierce intellectual with 
      a decidedly dark view of himself and the world. Frost would use rural 
      settings as a metaphor for his philosophical views. Robert Frost is one of 
      the best-known and most loved of American poets. He died in Boston on 
      January 29, 1963.</p>

   <p>Two of Frost's poems are included below. Click the sound icon located next
      to each poem to hear readings of each work.</p>


   <div class="poem">

      <h2>Fire and Ice</h2>

      <p>
         <!--[if IE]><!-->
            <object data="fireice.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"
                    classid="clsid:02bf25d5-8c17-4b23-bc80-d3488abddc6b"
                    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
                    width="17" height="16">
                    <param name="src" value="fireice.mp3" />
                <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                <param name="controller" value="true" />
                <p>Click to <a href="fireice.mp3">download</a> the sound clip</p>
            </object>
         <!--<![endif]-->
         <!--[!IE]><!-->
            <object data="fireice.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"
                    width="17" height="16">
         <!--<![endif]-->
                <param name="src" value="fireice.mp3" />
                <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                <param name="controller" value="true" />
                <p>Click to <a href="fireice.mp3">download</a> the sound clip</p>
            </object>
         <!--<![endif]-->
         Some say the world will end in fire,<br />
         Some say in ice.<br />
         From what I've tasted of desire<br />
         I hold with those who favor fire.<br />
         But if it had to perish twice,<br />
         I think I know enough of hate<br />
         To say that for destruction ice<br />
         Is also great<br />
         And would suffice.
      </p>
   </div>

   <div class="poem">
   <h2>Devotion</h2>
   <p>
          <!--[if IE]><!-->
            <object data="devotion.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"
                    classid="clsid:02bf25d5-8c17-4b23-bc80-d3488abddc6b"
                    codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab"
                    width="17" height="16">
                    <param name="src" value="fireice.mp3" />
                <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                <param name="controller" value="true" />
                <p>Click to<a href="devotion.mp3">download</a>the sound clip</p>
            </object>
         <!--<![endif]-->
         <!--[!IE]><!-->
            <object data="devotion.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"
                    width="17" height="16">
                <param name="src" value="fireice.mp3" />
                <param name="autoplay" value="false" />
                <param name="controller" value="true" />
                <p>Click to<a href="devotion.mp3">download</a>the sound clip</p>
            </object>
         <!--<![endif]-->
         The heart can think of no devotion<br />
         Greater than being shore to the ocean&#151;<br />
         Holding the curve of one position,<br />
         Counting an endless repetition.
      </p>
   </div>

   <div id="footer">
      Button applet provided by: 
     <a href="http://www.free-applets.com">http://www.free-applets.com</a>
   </div>

   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body                 {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-size: 15px; 
                      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                      background-image: url(tan.jpg)}

#pageContent         {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 30px; width: 700px}

#links               {text-align: center; font-size: 10px}
#links a             {margin: 0px 10px}

#head                {text-align: center; margin-top: 10px}

.firstp:first-letter {float: left; font-size: 300%; line-height: 0.7; 
                      margin: 0px 3px 3px 0px}
.firstp:first-line   {font-variant: small-caps}

h2                   {font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 3px; margin: 0px}
.poem p              {margin: 10px}

.poem                {float: left; margin-right: 20px}


#footer              {border-top: 1px solid black; width: 100%; text-align: right; 
                      font-size: 10px; clear: left; padding-bottom: 10px}
```

Comment: For what it's worth: please ignore everything you are being taught in this exercise. Using Java applets for links went out of style around 1997.

Comment: Bah, applets rule! forget what is said ^ . Umm, Loook, the issue here is that this looks like a homework assignment, with alot of stuff 2 do. it's hard to help, try to narrow this down

Comment: @Adel Narrow it down to what? I thought I was pretty specific about the issues I was having.